# jquery-plugin columnizer: is it really so slow?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using jquery-plugin columnizer
http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

It is sometimes very slow to create the columns (you can try changing the browser window size, or selecting a filter.

Sometimes Firefox gives the error message: "Unresponsive Javascript script" and I have to press on continue to continue the navigation.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved by compressing and compacting the js files. Now the performance is good. Check Google page speed.

Answer (score 3):

You've got a **HELL** of a lot of stuff included in that page - especially for such a simple design. I count at least 14 JavaScript includes and tons of CSS files which comes to around 330 KB in total. I'm not surprised it performs poorly with all that scripting. I also note that the page doesn't render at all in IE8 (which, like it or not, is still the most widely used browser). And on browsers where it does render, the column manager makes the columns jump around when loading, which doesn't look too great.

Personally I would look at stripping out all the unnecessary JavaScript and just stick to what you actually need to execute for that page. I'd also look at just using [CSS to layout the page](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-multi-column-liquid-layouts) - do you *really* need columnizer?

Comment: 1) Amount of Javascript: Exactly, it is Drupal. 2) About using CSS: Multi-column layout is currently only supported in Mozilla based browsers and Safari 3, who have prefixed the properties with respectively -moz- and -webkit-. 3) I'm pretty sure it is the colunizer plugin taking so long and not other javascripts, I've tested it on a single page, and it is slow as well. 4) Please I need some help, have you ever implemented multi columns website for all browsers ? Any tips ?

Comment: it is still work in progress, I know IE is not working, this wasn't my question at all. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Addtional to what Dan Diplo said: Several current browsers support "newspaper columns" via CSS.

http://www.css3.info/preview/multi-column-layout/

Comment: Multi-column layout is currently only supported in Mozilla based browsers and Safari 3, who have prefixed the properties with respectively -moz- and -webkit-.